# Android:image animation using separate layout

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-animation

I am building an app for wallpaper. I am trying get image from server. I am able to get image from server but when I am trying to animate and change image of imageview and it is work but it work in only in last 13 images not on all images. So how can I set animation for all the images? Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.featuredwallpaper;


import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status_code";
    public static final String TAG_ARRAY = "info";
    JSONArray images = null;
    LinearLayout ResultDisplayLayout;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    String projectName = "Heart";
    public static String url = "http://frontlinkinfotech.com/lwp/c_wall/get_images";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    SquareImageViewHalf  image1,image2, image4, image5, image7, image8,
            image12, image13;
    SquareImageView image3, image6, image9, image10, image11;
    ArrayList<SquareImageViewHalf> image1animation = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ResultDisplayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ResultDisplayLayout);
        new LoadImages().execute();
        handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    private Animation selectAnimation(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
        case 1:
            return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left);
        case 2:
            return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wave_scale);
        case 3:
            return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hold);
        case 4:
            return new AnimationUtils().loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_enter);
        }
        return null;
    }

    void handleChangeImage(final int id) {

        Handler hand = new Handler();
        hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random rand = new Random();

                int index = rand.nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length);

                // handleChangeImage();
                switch (id) {
                case R.id.imageView1:
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image1,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[index], R.drawable.ima);
                        image1.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math
                                .random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView2);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image2,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image2.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView3);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image3,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image3.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView4);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView4:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image4,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image4.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView5);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView5:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image5,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image5.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView6);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView6:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image6,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image6.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView7);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView7:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image7,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image7.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView8);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView8:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image8,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image8.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView9);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView9:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image9,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image9.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView10);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView10:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image10,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image10.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView11);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView11:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image11,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image11.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView12);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView12:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image12,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image12.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView13);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView13:
                    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image13,
                            CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[rand
                                    .nextInt(CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length)],
                            R.drawable.ima);
                    image13.startAnimation(selectAnimation((int) (Math.random() * 5)));
                    handleChangeImage(R.id.imageView1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, 4000);

    }

    class LoadImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            Log.d("back", "in background");
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cat_name", projectName));
            String uuu = "http://frontlinkinfotech.com/lwp/c_wall/get_all_images";
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(uuu, "POST", params);
            Log.d("back", "get image");
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (success == 200) {
                    Log.d("back", "success");
                    images = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
                    for (int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++) {

                        String jkr = images.getString(i);
                        String front = jkr.replace("jkrdevelopers",
                                "frontlinkinfotech");

                        list1.add(front);
                    }
                    CC.IMAGES_POPULAR = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
                    // Collections.shuffle(list1);
                    Log.d("Array", CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.toString());
                    Log.d("Array", list1.toString());
                    // CC.IMAGES_NEW = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("back", "in post");
                ResultDisplayLayout.removeAllViews();

                Log.d("Size", CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length + "");
                Log.d("Size", CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length / 13 + "");
                for (int i = 0; i < CC.IMAGES_POPULAR.length / 13; i++) {
                    // Display_Toast_Message(collect_rs_rd_value.get(i));
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_listview, null);

                    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                         image1 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image1,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i], R.drawable.ima);

                        image2 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image2,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 1], R.drawable.ima);

                        image3 = (SquareImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image3,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 2], R.drawable.ima);

                        image4 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image4,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 3], R.drawable.ima);

                        image5 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image5,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 4], R.drawable.ima);

                        image6 = (SquareImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image6,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 5], R.drawable.ima);

                        image7 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image7,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 6], R.drawable.ima);

                        image8 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image8,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 7], R.drawable.ima);

                        image9 = (SquareImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image9,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 8], R.drawable.ima);

                        image10 = (SquareImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image10,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 9], R.drawable.ima);

                        image11 = (SquareImageView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView11);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image11,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 10], R.drawable.ima);

                        image12 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView12);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image12,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 11], R.drawable.ima);

                        image13 = (SquareImageViewHalf) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.imageView13);
                        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(image13,
                                CC.IMAGES_POPULAR[i + 12], R.drawable.ima);

                    }

                    ResultDisplayLayout.addView(view);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "post",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.featuredwallpaper.MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ResultDisplayLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**image_listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="NestedWeights,DisableBaselineAlignment" >

   <!--  start first layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
      ></LinearLayout>


    <!-- end second layout -->


    <!-- start third layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
      ></LinearLayout>

    <!-- end third layout -->


    <!-- start fourth Layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <com.example.featuredwallpaper.SquareImageViewHalf
                android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
      ></LinearLayout>


    <!-- end fourth Layout -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
package com.example.featuredwallpaper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**CC.java**

```
package com.example.featuredwallpaper;

public class CC {
    public static String[] IMAGES_POPULAR;
    public static String[] IMAGES_NEW;
    public static int pos=0;
    public static String imageName;
    public static int totalClick;

    public static class Extra {
        public static final String IMAGES = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGES";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }
}
```

**SquareImageView.java**

```
package com.example.featuredwallpaper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageView extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

**SquareImageViewHalf.java**

```
package com.example.featuredwallpaper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageViewHalf extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageViewHalf(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageViewHalf(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageViewHalf(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()/2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading images to view in Android is a big problem. Because of the limited cache size. I think this [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-0) may help you.